# Program repeats entries in output

Tags: java

Program code works correctly, except the output repeats some of the 
inputs. I can't seem to figure out why it repeats the first entry as well as the last entry.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 8;             // Number of elements
        int[] userVals = new int[NUM_ELEMENTS]; // User input
        int i = 0;                              // Loop index
        int greaterVal = 0;                     // Find greater #'s than 21

        // Prompt user to populate array 
        System.out.println("Enter " + NUM_ELEMENTS + " integer values...");
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
           System.out.println("Value: ");
           userVals[i] = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        // Determine #'s greater than 21
        int greaterVal = userVals[0];
        System.out.print("#'s greater than 21 are: ");
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
            if (userVals[i] >= 21) {
                greaterVal = userVals[i];
            }
            // Code is supposed to only display #'s greater than 21 once
            System.out.print(" " + greaterVal + " ");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect/want? Also give US your input regarding to the output

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to debug your code for you. This kind of question isn't helpful to others browsing the site unless you specify a specific part of the code which isn't working as expected. You can use these [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) in order to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Jérôme I've reviewed every compile warning and it still displays the same thing. I apologize this isn't helpful and will continue to play with the code to get the right output. I use 3, 2, 230, 258, 234, 73, 27, -2 and I get back 3 3 230 258 234 73 27 27

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
       if (userVals[i] >= 21) {
       greaterVal = userVals[i];
    }
    // Code is supposed to only display #'s greater than 21 once

    System.out.print(" " + greaterVal + " ");
    }
```

formatting is very bad, and this fragment is not correct. You should print value at once, not save it for later.

Comment: Yes, got it :) @borowis

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have mention `System.out.print(" " + greaterVal + " ");` out side of condition  `if (userVals[i] >= 21)`, that why if current value in loop less then 21 and if previous  value was greater then 21 value which is hold by greaterVal variable then it will print previous value again . 
update your code

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
            if (userVals[i] >= 21) {
                greaterVal = userVals[i];
            // Code is supposed to only display #'s greater than 21 once
            System.out.print(" " + greaterVal + " ");
            }    
        }
```

Also if you just need to print the greater then 21 values, then you don't need greaterVal variable, you just need this

```
 for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
                if (userVals[i] >= 21) {
                // Code is supposed to only display #'s greater than 21 once
                System.out.print( " "+ userVals[i] + " ");
                }    
            }
```

Comment: Played around with moving  the print statement around, and came up with exactly what you suggested in your response.... Gracias